# How to get highlighted searches on whoosh

Tags: python, highlighting, whoosh

I used an example code from pythonhosted.org but nothing seems to happen. This is code I used:

```
results = mysearcher.search(myquery)
for hit in results:
    print(hit["title"])
```

I entered this code into python but it gives an error saying `mysearcher is not defined`. So I'm really not sure if I'm missing something out as I'm just trying to get the basics to get me up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to define the searcher `mysearcher`, copy the whole code. Here is a complete example:

```
>>> import whoosh
>>> from whoosh.index import create_in
>>> from whoosh.fields import *
>>> schema = Schema(title=TEXT(stored=True), path=ID(stored=True), content=TEXT)
>>> ix = create_in("indexdir", schema)
>>> writer = ix.writer()
>>> writer.add_document(title=u"First document", path=u"/a",
...                     content=u"This is the first document we've added!")
>>> writer.add_document(title=u"Second document", path=u"/b",
...                     content=u"The second one is even more interesting!")
>>> writer.commit()
>>> from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
>>> with ix.searcher() as searcher:
...     query = QueryParser("content", ix.schema).parse("first")
...     results = searcher.search(query)
...     results[0]
...
{"title": u"First document", "path": u"/a"}
```

Than you can highlight like this:

```
for hit in results:
    print(hit["title"])
    # Assume "content" field is stored
    print(hit.highlights("content"))
```

Comment: I tried that as well earlier but this is the error it gives: `ImportError: No module named 'whoosh'`

Comment: you should do `import whoosh`

Comment: and you should install whoosh for sure `sudo pip install whoosh`

Comment: I added `import whoosh` at the beginning of the code but still it gives the same error

Comment: where exactly do I write the code for the installation, is that still on python or command line ?

Comment: No I am currently on Windows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96893/discussion-between-jayjay-simpson-and-bigother).